# JSON Stringfy only a few properties

Tags: javascript, json

I have this object:

```
{
    name: "",            
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    protocol: "",
    area: "",
    subject: "",
    message: "",
    validation: this.validator.valid()
}
```

I wanna convert it to JSON, but I do not want the `validation` property on it.

I've already tried the following:

```
const test = JSON.stringify(this.state);
delete test.validation;
```

Any other approach?

Comment: you want to select which property to stringify?

Comment: Yeah, @Webwoman 
I've updated the question: look what've tried. It worked for me ;)

Comment: Ok, @Yunnosch, im sorry. I'll do it

Comment: No problem, well done now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excluding object properties while json-stringifying array object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465657/excluding-object-properties-while-json-stringifying-array-object)

Comment: @HereticMonkey i've answered mine question with the solution that worked for me. It seems to be a different solution and use case than the question you referenced proposes.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter)? It contains the answer to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) takes a replacer callback you can use. The replacer function takes a key `k` and the value `v` being stringified as parameters. Returning undefined will have the effect of not including the key in the final result:

```js
state = {
    name: "",            
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    protocol: "",
    area: "",
    subject: "",
    message: "",
    validation: "some val"
}

const test = JSON.stringify(state, (k, v) => k != 'validation' ? v : undefined);

console.log(test)
```

Note: used like this it will remove the `validation` key from any child objects as well, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks, man! I found the answer b'cause of your post. I've updated the question with my solution: what do you think of it? There's any problem? I'm brand new to this whole thing ;)

Comment: can you extrapolate the meaning of `k` and `v` for the future readers please

Comment: Sure @Webwoman, I added some extra text explaining it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It will work.

```
const { validation, ...rest } = this.state;
JSON.stringify(rest);
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE - I found a different solution**

It's very simple, in fact. I've discovered the solution [here](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/filter.php). 
The following lines solved my problem:

```
const formSubmit = JSON.stringify(this.state, ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'protocol','area','subject', 'message']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put an undefined, JSON.stringify will skip it:

```
const yourState = {
        name: "",            
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        protocol: "",
        area: "",
        subject: "",
        message: "",
        validation: true,
    }

const copy = {
  ...yourState,
  validation: undefined,
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(copy));
```

Also, you can not perform a delete from JSON.stringify because it is a string an not an object literal.