# Php regex: remove order by from query string

Tags: php, regex

I have a php method, which should remove all occurences of an "order by" mysql statement from a mysql query string.

**Example 1:**

STRING: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name`

RESULT: `SELECT * FROM table`

**Example 2:**

STRING: `SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name, creation_date) AS a ORDER BY a.name`

Result: `SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT * FROM table) AS a`

My question now is: How to achive this.

I have tried the following:

```
if (stripos($sql, 'ORDER BY') !== false) {
    $sql = preg_replace('/\sORDER\ BY.+/i', '', $sql);
}
```

But this would work for example 1, but not for example 2

Comment: Have you tried something or are you just asking us to write your code and do your work?

Comment: Please state what you tried.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't finished with my quesion and published it to fast.

Answer (score 4):

Regex you can use is `ORDER BY.*?(?=\s*LIMIT|\)|$)`.

Sample code:

```
$re = "/ORDER BY.*?(?=\\s*LIMIT|\\)|$)/mi"; 
$str = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name\n\nSELECT a.* FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name, created_at) AS a ORDER BY a.name\n\nSELECT t0.* FROM table t0 WHERE t0.created_at IS NOT NULL ORDER BY t0.name, t0.created_at, t0.status LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jS5fN1/4)

Comment: Nope. Your regex removes the end of the string of example 2 as well. see https://regex101.com/r/hC0pF7/1 . The answer of vks works

Comment: I have updated to `[\\w.]+` that will only match letters, numbers, "_" and dots.

Comment: neither your demo, nor your sample code work. in the demo, you produce broken sql code, and your sample code doesn't replace anything at all

Comment: Sorry, I see now what you meant. I have updated the regex, code and link in the answer.

Comment: thank you. you got +1, but I have already accepted vks answer

Comment: :) I also upvoted your question. If you think that suggestion is what you need, it's OK. I just wanted to add that if performance matters, consider this speed comparison: `(?i)order by ([\w., ]+)` finishes in 18 + 21 + 15 steps, and `ORDER BY.*?(?=\)|$)` finishes in 32 + 78 + 36 steps.

Comment: @stribizhev no. of steps is never a measure of performance.read here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093501/atomic-groups-clarity

Comment: @stribizhev also your regex will break if query is `SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name, c@#reation_date) AS a ORDER BY a.name` ie it has `#@` etc.So this way is fragile :)

Comment: @vks: Database column names do not usually contain such symbols.

Comment: Since neither your, nor vks code works in some cases, I need your help again - see https://regex101.com/r/jS5fN1/1

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY.*?(?=\)|$)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty space`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/22

```
$re = "/ORDER BY.*?(?=\\)|$)/mi";
$str = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name\nSELECT a.* FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name, creation_date) AS a ORDER BY a.name";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Yes, I had to wait some minutes because of SO, so that I can accept it. But now, I have accepted it.

Comment: Ok, your regex isn't working correct in all cases. Please have a look at https://regex101.com/r/jS5fN1/1 - here its removing the limit and the offset as well :/

Comment: @vks The above breaks when you include direction, e.g. `ORDER BY name DESC, created_at`