# Remove last order by clause from SQL Query using php regex

Tags: php, regex

I have following query

```
select id,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))) AS  SerialNo,name,address from customer order by name
```

Now i want to remove last order by from query while keeping SerialNo. Here i will have multiple queries so order by field will be changed yet it will be only single field.

I tried to use the [Php regex: remove order by from query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231433/php-regex-remove-order-by-from-query-string) answer yet it removes all the order by from the string which is not what i want.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ What is the X problem to the Y that you've posted?

Comment: [`preg_replace('/(.+) order by.*/i',"$1",$sql)`](https://tio.run/##PY1NC4JAFEX3/oqHCM7UoLi2iCyhRamMfdBKzHmloI3N2KJfP@nGzT1cOJfb170xq012yCzL0Z8W1mBrbLEaoBGM8PRWJJdTFHNCIb3GHEjK9yOiO5A8Psa7MwSUUtjmADmqpmwTyd5lh6wUQqHW8FSyg@qrB9mhAqnEmI8fTI4dzqe9wlehsG/LConrE29JZ9db@C6zncBmk0zHEVa1hKmExvwB) to cut off the string at last `order by`

Comment: @bobblebubble that won't work if there's a `LIMIT` clause after the `ORDER BY`

Comment: @bobblebubble i also want to get that order by field rather then just remove it. How is it possible?

Comment: If you have at least 2 ORDER BY and no succeeding string after the last one, then you can try this `/.*(order by .*)/i` , it can capture all characters after the last ORDER BY as a group and then you can replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is detecting the end of an `order by` clause in the general case. These are some examples:

1. `select * from (select * from t order by x, y) sq`
2. `select * from t order by x limit 1`
3. `select * from t order by (select 1)`

Here I am working on the assumption that the `order by` clause you are interested in is at the end of the sql statement and includes everything through the end of that statement. Under that assumption:

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1obiSI/2/)

```
<?php

$sql = 'select id,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))) AS  SerialNo,name,address from customer order by name';

if (preg_match('/.*(\border\s+by\s+.*)/is', $sql, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    $orderBy = $matches[1][0];
    $offset = $matches[1][1];
    $newSql = substr($sql, 0, $offset);
    echo "The order by clause was: '$orderBy'.\n";
    echo "The new sql is: '$newSql'.\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
The order by clause was: 'order by name'.
The new sql is: 'select id,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))) AS  SerialNo,name,address from customer '.
```