# Why my replacer function in JSON.stringify(value, replacer) doesn't receive keys in Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, stringify

Trying to implement JSON.stringify as explained here: [Hide certain values in output from JSON.stringify()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910567/json-stringify-how-to-exclude-certain-fields-from-the-json-string) and exclude some fields from serialization but it doesn't work.

For example in my controller I've the following code:

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.event = {
      id:1,
      title: 'event title',
      users: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Anatoly'
      },{
        id: 2,
        name: 'Roman'
      }],
      private1: 1,
      private2: 2
    };



    var replacer = function(key, value){
        console.log(key);
    };

    $scope.stringified1 = JSON.stringify($scope.event, replacer);

    // $scope.stringified = JSON.stringify($scope.event, ['id','title','users','name']);

 }]);
```

Why `console.log(key)` prints nothing? The function itself is invoked, but `key` parameter is empty.

I've done plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/U6ZcIuPVr5RzMIBl8X6c?p=preview

I'm using Angular 1.4.9 and Chrome 48.0.2564.116

P.S. I've done this functionality with passed array and it works, but using a function can give a much more flexibility so I'd like to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: replacer doesn't return anything. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually you helped me to solve this issue, if I not return on a first call any value it won't be called on a following properties :) See updated plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/h9NU2xppeGuMSTfTyRng?p=preview  and thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it isn't clear from manual here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify  but because `replacer` called in a recursively manner it should return object on which it's being called, root object itself too:

> Initially it gets called with an empty key representing the object
>   being stringified

you should return this object, if you return nothing it won't be called on other properties of this object

> and it then gets called for each property on the object or array
>   being stringified

So, thanks to @charlietfl hint, I fixed it, you can see fixed plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/a3S8yGx78b7vJSKwORw5?p=preview