# Create transient JavaScript variable in an object

Tags: javascript, oop

```
function Player(name)
    {            
        this._name = name;                     
        this._id = "Player"+(Player_ID++);
    };

var newPlayer = new Player(newUnitName);
alert(JSON.stringify(newPlayer));
```

What I want to do is stop displaying the id value. Is there a way to make the id variable tranient.
Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json stringify : How to exclude certain fields from the json string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910567/json-stringify-how-to-exclude-certain-fields-from-the-json-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every object has a method `toJSON()`, which is invoked when the object should be serialize using `JSON.stringify()`.

From [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on JSON.stringify():

> If an object being stringified has a property named `toJSON` whose value
>   is a function, then the `toJSON()` method customizes JSON
>   stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the
>   value returned by the `toJSON()` method when called will be serialized

---

The following example creates a different serialization function, which will exclude the `_id`:

```
var Player_ID = 0;
function Player(name) {            
 this._name = name;                     
 this._id = "Player"+(Player_ID++);
 this.toJSON = function() {
   return {
     _name: this._name
   };
 };
};

var newPlayer = new Player('Name 1');
console.log(JSON.stringify(newPlayer)); // prints {"_name": 'Name 1'}
```

Check the working [demo](http://jsbin.com/hesihifugu/1/edit?js,console).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to enumerate over this property you can use [non-enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Enumerable_attribute) properties:

```js
    function Player(name)
        {            
            this._name = name;                     
            Object.defineProperty(this, '_id', {
              enumerable: false
            });
        };

    var newUnitName = "Foo";
    var newPlayer = new Player(newUnitName);
    alert(JSON.stringify(newPlayer));
```

Comment: How we can access `console.log(newPlayer._id)`?

Answer (score 0):

Targeting ES2022, you can achieve transient variables at least in 2 ways:

1. Using a private variable
2. Using an "accessor" variable

```js
"use strict";
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.#aTransientValue_accessor_storage = "transient";
        this.aNormalValue = "public";
        this.#aPrivateValue = "public";
    }
    #aTransientValue_accessor_storage;
    get aTransientValue() { return this.#aTransientValue_accessor_storage; }
    set aTransientValue(value) { this.#aTransientValue_accessor_storage = value; }
    #aPrivateValue;
}
const example = new Example();
console.log(example); /// prints { "aNormalValue": "public" }
```

Typescript even introduced the "accessor" keyword, which can be used for [this purpose.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=3#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUD6B0Yww6UA9gE5EAqlYAdhAJboMAuAamCAK6YBeaACJ29Jqw7CA3PkIpeAIxDNgRAHJUkPbn0EiFy1cLkEAxGAAKlZgDcw7dLv7QhwwyuAmcAXzzByJnZodERUDFdoBnQAdzgwtHQACgBKWRwApnIMADoQcgBzJNDkRLSgA)

Here is the TS equivalent code:

```js
class Example {
    accessor aTransientValue = "transient";
    public aNormalValue = "public"
    #aPrivateValue = "public"
}

const example = new Example();

console.log(example);
```