# How to ignore an entity field in TypeScript when sending a JSON to a Web Service?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have this class:

```
export class TblColabAdmin {
    snomatrcompl: string;
    nflativo: number;
    ativo: boolean;
}
```

The attribute *ativo* doesn't exist in my web service entity, so I would like to avoid that it was added in JSON.

In Java, for example, we have *@JsonIgnore* annotation. Does exist something similar in TypeScript?

Comment: nope, you need to create a new object and set only the properties you want to send.

Comment: Did you look at adding a 'toJSON' method? You could tr something like `toJSON() { const obj = Object.assign({}, this); delete obj.ativo; return obj; }`. Or `toJSON() { return Object.assign({}, this, {ativo: undefined}); }`.

Comment: Using a custom replacer as suggested in this answer will help, I believe.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41685627/2685234

Comment: Found one more approach of having toJSON function in each type.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35138341/2685234

Answer (score 11):

You can create a `JsonIgnore` [decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators) so that it will work like with java:

```
const IGNORE_FIELDS = new Map<string, string[]>();
function JsonIgnore(cls: any, name: string) {
    let clsName = cls.constructor.name;
    let list: string[];

    if (IGNORE_FIELDS.has(clsName)) {
        list = IGNORE_FIELDS.get(clsName);
    } else {
        list = [];
        IGNORE_FIELDS.set(clsName, list);
    }

    list.push(name);
}

class Base {
    toJson(): { [name: string]: any } {
        let json = {};
        let ignore = IGNORE_FIELDS.get(this.constructor.name);

        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).filter(name => ignore.indexOf(name) < 0).forEach(name => {
            json[name] = this[name];
        });

        return json;
    }
}

class TblColabAdmin extends Base {
    snomatrcompl: string;
    nflativo: number;

    @JsonIgnore
    ativo: boolean;

    constructor(snomatrcompl: string, nflativo: number, ativo: boolean) {
        super();

        this.snomatrcompl = snomatrcompl;
        this.nflativo = nflativo;
        this.ativo = ativo;
    }
}

let obj = new TblColabAdmin("str", 43, true).toJson();
console.log(obj); // Object {snomatrcompl: "few", nflativo: 43}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20GTree%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20createNode(name%3A%20string)%3A%20GNode%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20GNodeImpl(name)%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20GNode%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20GNodeImpl%20implements%20GNode%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%7D%0A%7D#src=function%20extend%3CT%3E(list%3A%20T%5B%5D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%20swap(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(list%20as%20T%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%20swap(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7D).swap%20%3D%20function%20(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20tmp%20%3D%20this%5Bi1%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bi1%5D%20%3D%20this%5Bi2%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5Bi2%5D%20%3D%20tmp%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20list%20as%20T%5B%5D%20%26%20%7B%20swap(i1%3A%20number%2C%20i2%3A%20number)%3A%20void%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20list%20%3D%20extend(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D)%3B%0Alist.swap(0%2C%202)%3B%0Aconsole.log(list)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B3%2C%202%2C%201%5D#src=class%20CustomError%20extends%20Error%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20super(%60Lorem%20%22%24%7Bmessage%7D%22%20ipsum%20dolor.%60)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20'CustomError'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Athrow%20new%20CustomError('foo')%3B#src=class%20CustomError%20extends%20Error%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(message%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20super(%60Lorem%20%22%24%7Bmessage%7D%22%20ipsum%20dolor.%60)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20'CustomError'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Athrow%20new%20CustomError('foo')%3B#src=const%20IGNORE_FIELDS%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E()%3B%0Afunction%20JsonIgnore(cls%3A%20any%2C%20name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20clsName%20%3D%20cls.constructor.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20list%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(IGNORE_FIELDS.has(clsName))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20IGNORE_FIELDS.get(clsName)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20IGNORE_FIELDS.set(clsName%2C%20list)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20list.push(name)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20toJson()%3A%20%7B%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20json%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20ignore%20%3D%20IGNORE_FIELDS.get(this.constructor.name)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).filter(name%20%3D%3E%20ignore.indexOf(name)%20%3C%200).forEach(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20json%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20this%5Bname%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20json%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20TblColabAdmin%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20snomatrcompl%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20nflativo%3A%20number%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%40JsonIgnore%0A%20%20%20%20ativo%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(snomatrcompl%3A%20string%2C%20nflativo%3A%20number%2C%20ativo%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.snomatrcompl%20%3D%20snomatrcompl%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.nflativo%20%3D%20nflativo%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.ativo%20%3D%20ativo%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20new%20TblColabAdmin(%22str%22%2C%2043%2C%20true).toJson()%3B%0Aconsole.log(obj)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Object%20%7Bsnomatrcompl%3A%20%22few%22%2C%20nflativo%3A%2043%7D))

It's quite a lot of work if you're only doing it once, but if it's a common issue in your code then this approach should work well.

Comment: This works well if you are not using the JSON.stringify, in other case a good approach is using a replacer as suggested in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685082/how-to-ignore-properties-sent-via-http/41685627#41685627

Comment: I use this in my project and extend all my classes from the Base class. Just make sure to check `let ignore` before you filter because if you do not have a `@JsonIgnore` in your class it will be undefined and `json` will be `{}`. So `if(!ignore) json = this;`

Comment: @LukeKroon I updated this code for a property which is ref of another class having same kind of functionality

Comment: @GouravGarg your edit changes my reply, which is old and i prefer to keep it as is. you're welcome to write a new answer with your improved code.