# How to ignore properties sent via http

Tags: http, angular, typescript

I have an interface in my application that maintains properties that I want to send to my database, as well as properties that I do not.

Specifically I maintain an property called `state` that can be set to `open` or `null` (closed) which then triggers Angular2's Animation [state](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/state-function.html) function. I use this in `*ngFor` lists to open an close a panel of information about the item.

However, I don't want to store the value of state in my database since it always defaults to `null`. Currently, I pass the whole object to the http call so the `state` property gets sent too. How can I instead ignore it?

```
  pushItemToDay(item: any, dateStr: Date): void {
    let body = JSON.stringify(item);

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    this.http.post(this.baseURL + 'api/addItem/' + dateStr, body, options)
        .toPromise()
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: before sending you can use delete myObject['property_name']; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910567/hide-certain-values-in-output-from-json-stringify :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delete can do damage if the object is used after the post. The function stringify has an additional parameter exactly to ignore unwanted entries.

```js
let source = {
  'meal': 'burger',
  'milkshake': 'chocolat',
  'extra':'2 hot dogs',
  'free': 'smile'
 };
let ignoreList = [ 'meal', 'extra' ];
 
function replacer(key,value)
{
    if (ignoreList.indexOf(key) > -1) return undefined;
    else return value;
}
 
let data = JSON.stringify(source, replacer);
console.log(data);
```